# In GeneXus, is there a Plugin developer guide?

Tags: plugins, genexus

I have an idea for a GeneXus plugin but have not found documentation on how that is done, can someone point me in the direction of how do build a plugin?

I see the marketplace is loaded with plugins, and I assume there is a standard way to do it, just need a little guide.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the kind of plugin you want to create are called "extensions" in Genexus.

If so, the documentation is here:
https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/wiki?4681,Getting+Started+with+GeneXus+Extensions